# spark count genetic mutations from tsv files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and distributed systems. Here I have data for 50 patients and the data for each patient is stored in a tsv file.

Each tsv file has a column called "mutation" and I want to count the mutation rate for each mutation. Mutation rate is defined as the number of mutated patients / the total number of patients (which is 50 here). If a mutation happens multiple times for one patient it will only count once. Any idea how to write in scala/python?

Input: 50 tsv files under same directory

Output: a frequency dictionary in the format: {mutation: mutation rate}

I know that in python this one works: but how should I write in spark?

```
def CalculateMutationRate(data:tsv_files):
    mutation_list=dict()
    for tsv_table in data:
        for mutation in set(tsv_table['mutation']):
            if mutation in mutation_list:
                mutation_list['mutation']+=1
            else:
                mutation_list['mutation']=1
    return mutation_list
```

The data looks like this, currently the first column means mutation and I only care about the first column. There are 50 tables in total.

[image]

Comment: show some data, that'd be easier for everyone to fully understand.

Comment: Hi Steven, I have already added a sample patient table.

Answer (score 1):

First load all the files into DataFrame:

```
df = spark.read.csv(path, sep='\t', header='true')
```

Then calculate rates like this:

```
df = df.groupBy('Hugo_Symbol').agg(count(col('*')).alias('ct'))\
       .withColumn('mutation_rate', col('ct')/sum('ct').over(Window.partitionBy()))\
       .drop('ct')
```

Finally convert the result to a dict:

```
freq_dict = df.rdd.collectAsMap()
```

Comment: how can I load multiple tables into one dataframe?

Comment: In `path` specify the folder path where you have all the files. Spark will load them all.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and got an error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'          Any idea with this error?

Comment: Thanks, I have already fixed this bug. Your answer helps a lot!